# Disabling output has no effect

Tags: r, garbage-collection, output, rcurl, verbosity

I noticed that, under some, unknown to me circumstances, some functions, whether from base `R` (for example, `gc()`), or from external packages (for example, `getCurlHandle()` from `RCurl`), still produce output, even after explicitly disabling it via `verbose = FALSE`. I am curious about reasons for such behavior. The only workaround I found on SO is the recommendation to call `invisible()`, but for me it worked only for `gc()`, but not for `getCurlHandle()`. Would appreciate any comments and answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While preparing a reproducible example, I figured this out. The source of the questionable output was not `getCurlHandle()`. It has been producing by another (next) function: `curlSetOpt()`. I took care of disabling its output by using `invisible()`.

It was really not bad, comparing with the effort I've made for figuring out my previous `R` and `RCurl` problem. But, it is always fun and educational.

Answer (score 1):

The command `gc(verbose=TRUE)`:

1. prints some statistics and percentages,
2. AND prints the matrix that is returned by the function.

The command `x=gc(verbose=TRUE)` only prints the statistics.

The command `gc(verbose=FALSE)` only prints the returned matrix.

The command `x=gc(verbose=FALSE)`prints nothing.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, +1! I confirm that the assignment operation forces `gc()` to print nothing. But the same approach doesn't work in the `getCurlHandle()` case. The message is: `An object of class "CURLHandle"\nSlot "ref":\n<pointer: 0x2408f90>`. Any ideas why?

Comment: It is the same.... 'x=getCurlHandle()' doesn't print anything, then 'x' prints the message you mentioned. (as x is indeed an object of class CurlHandle'

Comment: I have this line outside of any my functions in a module: `curl <- getCurlHandle()`. It produces the output I mentioned above, either as is, or even with `verbose = FALSE` argument. I run the code in a batch mode, not as an interactive session.

Comment: in the absence of a reproducible example, I can't help you

Comment: No problem. Actually, preparing a reproducible example helped me to figured this out. You were right: the assignment line was not the source of that output. Another (next) function was producing it. Again, thanks for your help.